# What methods are called when returning to UINavigationController's root view?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

What methods are called when returning to a previous view, or the root view, of a `UINavigationController`?

Also, when the user taps the back button to return to the previous view, is everything in the view that's disappearing released, and its values unretrievable from the parent view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`viewWillDisappear:animated:` will be called on a view controller before it is popped from the navigation stack.

This is the place to do anything that you need to do when the user goes "back" in the navigation controller. You can access any other controllers in the navigation stack via `self.navigationController.viewControllers` which is an array of all the view controllers currently in the stack, with the root view controller at index 0.

Comment: I have had problems with `viewWillDisappear:` and related methods not always being called inside a `UINavigationController`. I suggest you have your nav controller's delegate implement `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` and call a custom method on whichever view controller is being shown.

Comment: Interesting about the navigation controller stack. However as an example, if I go to say index 3 of the view controller and then return to index 2, will the value of a bool I created and set to true be lost? Or is it still retrievable after go back to the parent view? Or can you only retrieve variables from parents and not children?

Comment: You'd pass it to the parent controller in the above method. Or, which is more usual, your parent view controller would have passed some sort of "detail" object (i.e a managed object or dictionary) which the new controller has modified, there is then no need to "pass" anything back.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`, `viewWillDisappear` and `viewDidDisappear` in your view controllers. This works independently of `UINavigationController`.

Comment: I have had problems with `viewWillDisappear:` and related methods not always being called inside a `UINavigationController`. I suggest you have your nav controller's delegate implement `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` and call a custom method on whichever view controller is being shown.

Answer (score 2):

UINavigationController also has two delegate method. Maybe they would help you:

[navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UINavigationControllerDelegate/navigationController%3awillShowViewController%3aanimated%3a)
[navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UINavigationControllerDelegate/navigationController%3adidShowViewController%3aanimated%3a)